# DataSource connection as attribute works, while it results in an error when defined in App.Config

Tags: c#, unit-testing, datasource, app-config

Our testmethods connect to an Excel workbook through the DataSource attribute. It looks like:

```
[TestMethod, Priority(3)]
[DataSource("System.Data.OleDB",
            "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\TestDataWorkbook.xlsx; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=yes';",
            "TestDataSheet$",
            DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
```

And this works flawlessly. But when I try to add the same connection string in the App.Config like

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="microsoft.visualstudio.qualitytools" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestConfigurationSection, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestDataConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\TestDataWorkbook.xlsx; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=yes';" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <microsoft.visualstudio.qualitytools>
    <dataSources>
      <add name="MyTestData" connectionString="TestDataConnectionString" dataTableName="TestDataSheet$" dataAccessMethod="Sequential"/>
    </dataSources>
  </microsoft.visualstudio.qualitytools>
... other configuration settings
```

and try to connect to it with:

```
[TestMethod, Priority(3)]
[DataSource("MyTestData")]
```

it results in the following error:

```
The unit test adapter failed to connect to the data source or to read the data. For more information on troubleshooting this error, see "Troubleshooting Data-Driven Unit Tests" (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=62412) in the MSDN Library.
Error details: The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'MyTestData$'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.
```

The error resides in the sheetname. I have an connection to the workbook (checked it by renaming the workbook and the connectionstring), but the sheetname does not get recognized as a table name as it did in the first example.

Does someone recognize this situation or does someone have an hint in the right direction?

Comment: @Matt No, but what I did figure out: I am now using three `const`s as the datasource parameters. These **must** be `const` and not `readonly string`.

Answer (score 0):

Just paste this code on top of your test method:

```
[TestMethod, Priority(3)]
[DataSource("MyTestData"), TestMethod]
```

This will solve your problem :)